# JavaScript - How to delete an element from an array using deepmerge

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, element

I would like to be able to remove a value from my array but with deepmerge the array values only add up. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

```js
const dp = require('deepmerge');
const a = { moderation: { administrator_roleIds: [ '863696108285591562', '851483467047763978' ] } };

const b = { moderation: { administrator_roleIds: [ '863696108285591562' ] } };

dp(a, b);
// outpout => { moderation: { administrator_roleIds: [ '863696108285591562', '863696108285591562' ] } } or I want { moderation: { administrator_roleIds: [ '863696108285591562' ] } }
```

I need to use deepmerge because to modify my object I use a function using deepmerge, it would bother me to create another function knowing that I don't know how to do a deepmerge but inverse version of the merge (by removing items).

Comment: why you tagging `python`?

Comment: What the library does is in line with the definition of "merge".  You seem to want to get a *difference*. Different story. From the given example I don't get why you need anything "deep". Can you provide a less trivial example, that needs the solution to be "deep"?

Answer (score 0):

As per **deepmerge** definition:

> Merges the enumerable properties of two or more objects deeply.

You cant use **deepmerge** for deleting. Its use case is for merging.

For deleting an element of an array use the normal array methods.

```
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
delete fruits[0];
```